# Asynchronous data call on TCp Client/Server for large data

Tags: c#

I'm getting a image in bytes from a client device. A 3824726 bytes of data. This while loop will read till all the message is recieved. I'm facing a problem here. When it reads the byte till 3816534 and remaining 8192 bytes are left, it is just tripping off the while loop. No exception nothing. just going away. Please some one help reagding it. i'm not able to undersatnd what is the problem.

```
public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream stream, int initialLength)
{
    // If we've been passed an unhelpful initial length, justS
    // use 32K.
    if (initialLength < 1)
    {
        initialLength = 32768;
    }

    byte[] buffer = new byte[3824726];
    int read = 0;
    int chunk;
    try
    {

        while ((chunk = stream.Read(buffer, read, 3824726 - read)) > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Length of chunk" + chunk);
            read += chunk;
            Console.WriteLine("Length of read" + read);
            if (read == 0)
            {
                stream.Close();
                return buffer;
            }
            // If we've reached the end of our buffer, check to see if there's
            // any more information
            if (read == buffer.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Length of Buffer" + buffer.Length);
                int nextByte = stream.ReadByte();

                // End of stream? If so, we're done
                if (nextByte == -1)
                {
                    return buffer;
                }

                // Nope. Resize the buffer, put in the byte we've just
                // read, and continue
                byte[] newBuffer = new byte[buffer.Length * 2];
                Console.WriteLine("Length of newBuffer" + newBuffer.Length);
                Array.Copy(buffer, newBuffer, buffer.Length);
                newBuffer[read] = (byte)nextByte;
                buffer = newBuffer;
                read++;                        
            }
        }

        // Buffer is now too big. Shrink it.
        byte[] ret = new byte[read];
        Array.Copy(buffer, ret, read);
        return ret;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { throw ex; }
}
```

Comment: post all the code. the problem is in the lines not posted here. Your read is not asynchronous. Read into a giant buffer defeats the purpose of chunking.

Comment: You might have to show a *bit* more code.

Comment: I'm calling this Readfully message in a readcallback method. That is asyncronous type.

Comment: 3824726 is the actuall bytes which is comming. for testing pupose I had put it as 3824726 in the above code, otherwise it would be 'buffer.length'.

Comment: byte[] buffer = new byte[initialLength]; This is the original code.

Comment: after the size of read is becoming 3816534. It is just tripping out of the while loop. Please help. what to do? Where the problem is?

Comment: Unrelated: use `Buffer.BlockCopy` to copy data from `byte[]` to `byte[]`. It's _alot_ faster than `Array.Copy`.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis It is not coming to that loop itself. When the while condition becomes false it will come then to this code byte[] ret = new byte[read];
        Array.Copy(buffer, ret, read);
        return ret;

Comment: @Remus Rusanu | I've posted the code.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever | I've posted the code

Comment: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html. For reference this the site where I went through this function 'ReadFully'